# Ionic Framework Lifecycle

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

Is there **Ionic application lifecycle** like Android. I am asking this because I am developing an video application and **while my application went background** video still plays like android service or I push **hardware backbutton** video still plays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ionic framwork lets you develop the beautiful, hybrid mobile apps using open source front-end SDK and HTML5.

you can refer lifecycle events from http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionView/.

even you can handle one from [given](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/4.0.0/cordova_events_events.md.html) event to stop application from running when application goes into background.

You need to handle pause event to stop executing till application again resumed. again at the time of resume you can use `resume` event to again initialize.